# Hive Too many bytes before newline

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to run simple hive queries like

```
select * from table_name;
```

But getting error message as mentioned below.

```
Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:252)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many bytes before newline: 2147483648
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:67)
        ... 16 more
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 748  Reduce: 856   Cumulative CPU: 2938.2 sec   HDFS Read: 173243267086 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 48 minutes 58 seconds 200 msec
```

I could not find a way around this problem. I also looked into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990846/spark-read-json-throwing-java-io-ioexception-too-many-bytes-before-newline)

But could not find a way around Integer.MAX_VALUE. I would really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Assuming your row isn't 2147483648 bytes, I'd check to make sure your hive table is defined using the correct delimiter.

Comment: Table have XML data and keeping only single column for XML row. I think that might be why row is crossing 2147483648 bytes. 




Table DDL 



CREATE TABLE `v1_uspatentgrant`(
  `str` string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';

Comment: Could you suggest me a solution for this case where my single row size is going over 2.1 GB?